# Outlook Redemption unwrappedRdoMail adds 'B' character to empty HTML paragraph

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

We are seeing a change to the HTML body of a mail item when unwrapping the RDOMail from the unwrapped RDOStore.

We have tried with the latest Redemption code (5.23)

The code we are using follows:

```
RDOStores rdoStores;
RDOStore rdoStore, unwrappedRdoStore;
RDOFolder rdoFolder;
RDOMail unwrappedRdoMail;

using (_comObjectHelper.GetMonitor(rdoFolder = mail.Parent))
using (_comObjectHelper.GetMonitor(rdoStore = rdoFolder.Store))
using (_comObjectHelper.GetMonitor(rdoStores = rdoSession.Stores))
using (_comObjectHelper.GetMonitor(unwrappedRdoStore = rdoStores.UnwrapStore(rdoStore)))
using (_comObjectHelper.GetMonitor(unwrappedRdoMail = unwrappedRdoStore.GetMessageFromID(mail.EntryID)))
{
    rdoMailAction?.Invoke(unwrappedRdoMail);
    unwrappedRdoMail.Save();
}
```

IRDOMail item HTMLBody from `rdoSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(_MailItem)` (correct):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)\" />
    <style>
      <!--\r\n/* Font Definitions */\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Cambria Math\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:Calibri;\r\n\tpanose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}\r\n/* Style Definitions */\r\np.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\r\n\t{margin:0in;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-size:11.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;}\r\nspan.EmailStyle17\r\n\t{mso-style-type:personal-compose;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:windowtext;}\r\n.MsoChpDefault\r\n\t{mso-style-type:export-only;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;}\r\n@page WordSection1\r\n\t{size:8.5in 11.0in;\r\n\tmargin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}\r\ndiv.WordSection1\r\n\t{page:WordSection1;}\r\n-->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body lang=\"EN-US\" link=\"#0563C1\" vlink=\"#954F72\">
    <div class=\"WordSection1\">
      <p class=\"MsoNormal\">test </p>
      <p class=\"MsoNormal\"> </p>
      <p class=\"MsoNormal\">test </p>
      <p class=\"MsoNormal\"> </p>
      <p class=\"MsoNormal\">test</p>
      <p class=\"MsoNormal\"> </p>
      <p class=\"MsoNormal\">test test</p>
    </div>
    <span/>
  </body>
</html>\r\n
```

RDOMail unwrappedRdoMail item HTMLBody (incorrect - extra 'B' characters on blank paragraphs):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">
            <meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)\">
                <style>
                    <!--\r\n/* Font Definitions */\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Cambria Math\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:Calibri;\r\n\tpanose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}\r\n/* Style Definitions */\r\np.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\r\n\t{margin:0in;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-size:11.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;}\r\nspan.EmailStyle17\r\n\t{mso-style-type:personal-compose;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:windowtext;}\r\n.MsoChpDefault\r\n\t{mso-style-type:export-only;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;}\r\n@page WordSection1\r\n\t{size:8.5in 11.0in;\r\n\tmargin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}\r\ndiv.WordSection1\r\n\t{page:WordSection1;}\r\n-->
                </style>
            </head>
            <body lang=\"EN-US\" link=\"#0563C1\" vlink=\"#954F72\">
                <div class=\"WordSection1\">
                    <p class=\"MsoNormal\">test </p>
                    <p class=\"MsoNormal\">B </p>
                    <p class=\"MsoNormal\">test </p>
                    <p class=\"MsoNormal\">B </p>
                    <p class=\"MsoNormal\">test</p>
                    <p class=\"MsoNormal\"> </p>
                    <p class=\"MsoNormal\">test test</p>
                </div>
                <span/>
            </body>
        </html>\r\n
```

Has anyone seen this behaviour?  Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this happen for a particular message only? Can you save it as an MSG file, zip it (important!), and send to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out there was some funny characters `Â` and `a0` in the received email, which points to incompatibilities between the 2 different mail servers (GSuite and IMAP).

Nothing could be done in this case.